# Connecting to api via websocket using python

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve some information on cryptocurrencies from the api offered by https://lunarcrush.com, I have the following code:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection('wss://stream.lunarcrush.com/v2')
ws.send('auth:ly4qodsfafbqq0mr04lml') # must authenticate using command: auth:<api_key>

result = ws.recv()
print(f'Received: {result}')
```

But this returns

```
Received: {"action":"auth","error":"API
 key does not provide websocket access
"}
```

The only familiarity I have with APIs is going to <api.somewebsite.com> and using `requests` to parse the data, though I imagine this is not how it is supposed to be done.  I have never used the `websocket` package, but according to this website this how I am supposed to connect and I am using the api key they generated for me. Can anyone help with this? I am not even sure it there is a problem with the code, I see they offer a paid version but that says it is for commercial use, so I think I should be able to access the data via my free account? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure if the authentication string you've included here is legitimate or just a dummy value, but in the case of the former you should seek to invalidate it **as soon as possible**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error text is pretty clear; it's indicating that the subscription associated with the key you passed isn't allowed to access the WebSocket that LunarCRUSH publishes.

As they indicate on their [Pricing](https://lunarcrush.com/developers/pricing) page, the WebSocket connection is only made available to customers subscribing to their LunarStream or Enterprise tiers of service. If you're already subscribed at one of these tiers, I'd recommend opening a support ticket with them, as Stack Overflow can't diagnose issues on a provider's end (as much as we'd like to sometimes).

> I see they offer a paid version but that says it is for commercial use, so I think I should be able to access the data via my free account?

I would recommend reviewing the Pricing page I linked above -- it seems you have some misunderstanding on their subscription tiers, as it's indicated that even the Free tier is OK to use for commercial purposes.

Comment: I have a lot to learn.... thank you for answering despite the problem not being related to code at all @esqew  . Looks like I am going back to low budget web scraping.

Comment: No worries! I feel that this question is certainly within [the scope of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so I wouldn't worry too much about that aspect.